# Is this statement true or false ?:$\forall \epsilon >0,(\left|a\right|\le\epsilon\implies a=0)$

Tags: real-analysis, logic, solution-verification

Can someone help me demonstrate whether the following statement is true or false using pure logic:
***$$\forall \epsilon >0,\forall a\in\mathbb{R}(\left|a\right|\le\epsilon\implies a=0)$$***

My thought process: since we know that $\epsilon\neq0$ and $a=\epsilon$ that can't imply $a=0$, Therefore the statement is false and it should be $\left|a\right|<\epsilon\implies a=0$, but I'm not sure how to properly put this in logical math sense.

-Thanks for reading...

Comment: Note that $\forall\epsilon>0(|a|\le\epsilon)\implies a=0$ is true.

Comment: I don't get it isn't that the original statement we proved is false? ?

Comment: Note the slight change of bracketing. The statement would read in English, "Given $a$, for all positive $\epsilon$, if $|a|\le\epsilon$ then $a=0$". The statement we proved false reads: "For all positive $\epsilon$, for all real $a$, if $|a|\le\epsilon$ then $a=0$". Can you feel the difference?

Comment: I understand what you mean now, forgive me I'm still an amateur.Thanks a lot for the help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement should contain a quanitifier for $a$,$$\forall\epsilon>0,\forall a\in\Bbb R(|a|\le\epsilon\implies a=0)$$

The negation of your statement is$$\exists\epsilon>0,\exists a\in\Bbb R(|a|\le\epsilon\wedge a\ne0)$$The negation is true for $\epsilon=a=1$ hence the original statement is not true. A single counter-example is enough to falsify a statement.

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to quantify for a, thank you for your time i will edit it

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false.

Take $ a=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

we have $ |a|\le \epsilon $ but $ a\ne 0 $.

to be true, you should change the position of the parenthesis :

$$\forall a\in \Bbb R \;\; (\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; |a|\le \epsilon \implies a=0)$$

to prove it is true, assume that $ a\ne 0 $.

then there exist $ \epsilon =\frac{|a|}{2} $ such that

$$|a|>\epsilon$$

Comment: Clever, thank you very much

Comment: but if I proved that the statement is false at any $a$ in my case $a=0$ then the whole statement is wrong

Comment: Hi, but the last sentence must be $|a|\leq \epsilon=|a|/2$, or do I have done a mistake?